# Deriving a mathematical formulation for my recursive solution?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, knapsack-problem

In the question we have items with different values but all of the items weight doesn't matter. We have a goal of profit that we want to have by picking those items. But we want to have least amount of items and items are infinite.

So let's say our goal is 10 and we have items with values of 1,2,3,4. We want to have 4,4,2 rather than 3,3,3,1. They have same total value but what we wanted was the least amount of items with the same profit.

I already derived both dynamic and recursive methods to solve it but the trouble for me is that I just can not derive a mathematical formula for my recursive method.

Here is my recursive method

```java
static int recursiveSolution(int[] values, int goal, int totalAmount) {
        if (goal == 0)
            return totalAmount;
        if (goal < 0)
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        totalAmount++;
        int minAmount = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            minAmount = Math.min(minAmount, recursiveSolution(values, goal - values[i], totalAmount));
        }
        return minAmount;
    }
```

Comment: I think that this is actually the [change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) (a specific type of knapsack problem).  Also, what do you mean by "*a mathematical formula for it*"?  Can you give us an example? Or are you just asking for the CPU-complexity (Big-O) for this algorithm?

Comment: I mean like Recurrence Relation T(n) or Recursive formula like C(n)

Comment: I think that's because your recursive method is a combinatorial search and not numerical formula.  It is at most a semi-numerical relation and I can't recall seeing those expressed as a recurrence relation (they just don't fit  very well).  A combinatorial search isn't like a Fibonacci sequence or similar.  But I could be wrong, recurrence relations are definitely not my area of expertise.

Comment: FYI, here's a state of the art Change-Making Problem solver that I wrote for another question (though in that case the question assumed that there would always be an item with a value of 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you are asking for is the Big-O of your algorithm...

This looks like a simple brute-force summation search.  Unfortunately, the run-time of these are not easy to estimate and are dependent on the inputs values as well as their count (N).  The Big-O estimates that I have seen for this type of solution are something like this:

```
Let 
    N = the number of values in the `values[]` array,

    Gv = PRODUCT(values[])^(1/N)
        (the geometric mean of the `values[]` array),

    M = the target summation (`totalAmount`),

Then the complexity of the algorithm is (very approximately)

    O(N^(M/Gv))
```

If I recall this correctly.